# Adding rows to a table respecting the key columns structure

Tags: sql, r

I have a very large table, which follows these structure (I past it here simplified):

| Product | Line | Name | Quantity | Unit | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pepe | 10000 | Lucia | 4 | UD | 8 |
| Pepe | 20000 | Santiago | 7 | UD | 5.5 |
| Pepe | 30000 | Mariangeles | 10 | KG | 6 |
| Antonio | 10000 | Naiara | 4 | KG | 8 |
| Antonio | 20000 | Toni | 7 | KG | 3 |
| Vanesa | 10000 | Lucia | 4 | UD | 8 |
| Vanesa | 20000 | Santiago | 7 | KG | 8 |
| Vanesa | 30000 | Toni | 10 | KG | 3 |
| Vanesa | 40000 | Gines | 4 | KG | 8 |

I need to add a new Name (Dany) to every Product, so the table looks like this:

Name: Dany; Quantity:15; Unit: L; Cost: 2

The result would be:

| Product | Line | Name | Quantity | Unit | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pepe | 10000 | Lucia | 4 | UD | 8 |
| Pepe | 20000 | Santiago | 7 | UD | 5.5 |
| Pepe | 30000 | Mariangeles | 10 | KG | 6 |
| Pepe | 40000 | Dany | 15 | L | 2 |
| Antonio | 10000 | Naiara | 2 | KG | 8 |
| Antonio | 20000 | Toni | 7 | KG | 3 |
| Antonio | 30000 | Dany | 15 | L | 2 |
| Vanesa | 10000 | Lucia | 4 | UD | 8 |
| Vanesa | 20000 | Santiago | 7 | KG | 8 |
| Vanesa | 30000 | Toni | 10 | KG | 3 |
| Vanesa | 40000 | Gines | 4 | KG | 8 |
| Vanesa | 50000 | Dany | 15 | L | 2 |

The fact is that the 'line' has to be the subsequent number of the existing (for example, if the last Name of a product is 30000 (see Pepe), Dany's row line has to be 40000, if the last Name of a product is 20000, Dany's row line has to be 30000 (see Antonio)).

I can do it using SQL (DBeaver or Microsoft Access) or R, I am thinking about an R loop or a SQL complex query with count(), but some help would be very appreciated.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Comment: I use DBeaver or Microsoft Access to make these type of changes with SQL (last version both). The table has less than 1000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would insert the value into the table using `insert`:

```
insert into t (Product, Line, Name, Quantity, Unit, Cost)
    select product, max(line) + 10000, 'Dany', 15, 'L', 2
    from t
    group by product;
```

If you don't want to modify the table but just want to see the data, you can run a query:

```
select Product, Line, Name, Quantity, Unit, Cost
from t
union all
select product, max(line) + 10000, 'Dany', 15, 'L', 2
from t
group by product
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe SQL is likely the better place for this, but if you want to know how to do it in R, I'll assume you've already downloaded the relevant data into `dat`.

(In all three examples, the use of `order`/`arrange` is solely for presentation, not required in production.)

### base R

```r
newdat <- data.frame(Quantity=15L, Name="Dany", Unit="L", Cost=2)
newlines <- aggregate(dat$Line, list(Product=dat$Product), FUN=function(z) max(z) + 10000)
names(newlines)[2] <- "Line"
newlines
#   Product  Line
# 1 Antonio 30000
# 2    Pepe 40000
# 3  Vanesa 50000
out <- rbind(dat, merge(newlines, newdat, by = NULL))
out <- out[order(out$Product, out$Line),]
out
#    Product  Line        Name Quantity Unit Cost
# 4  Antonio 10000      Naiara        4   KG  8.0
# 5  Antonio 20000        Toni        7   KG  3.0
# 10 Antonio 30000        Dany       15    L  2.0
# 1     Pepe 10000       Lucia        4   UD  8.0
# 2     Pepe 20000    Santiago        7   UD  5.5
# 3     Pepe 30000 Mariangeles       10   KG  6.0
# 11    Pepe 40000        Dany       15    L  2.0
# 6   Vanesa 10000       Lucia        4   UD  8.0
# 7   Vanesa 20000    Santiago        7   KG  8.0
# 8   Vanesa 30000        Toni       10   KG  3.0
# 9   Vanesa 40000       Gines        4   KG  8.0
# 12  Vanesa 50000        Dany       15    L  2.0
```

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # crossing

# newdat from above
dat %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  summarize(Line = max(Line) + 10000) %>%
  tidyr::crossing(., newdat) %>%
  bind_rows(dat) %>%
  arrange(Product, Line)
# # A tibble: 12 x 6
#    Product  Line Quantity Name        Unit   Cost
#    <chr>   <dbl>    <int> <chr>       <chr> <dbl>
#  1 Antonio 10000        4 Naiara      KG      8  
#  2 Antonio 20000        7 Toni        KG      3  
#  3 Antonio 30000       15 Dany        L       2  
#  4 Pepe    10000        4 Lucia       UD      8  
#  5 Pepe    20000        7 Santiago    UD      5.5
#  6 Pepe    30000       10 Mariangeles KG      6  
#  7 Pepe    40000       15 Dany        L       2  
#  8 Vanesa  10000        4 Lucia       UD      8  
#  9 Vanesa  20000        7 Santiago    KG      8  
# 10 Vanesa  30000       10 Toni        KG      3  
# 11 Vanesa  40000        4 Gines       KG      8  
# 12 Vanesa  50000       15 Dany        L       2
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
newdatDT <- as.data.table(newdat)
newlinesDT <- datDT[, .(Line = max(Line) + 10000), by = .(Product)]

rbindlist(list(
  datDT,
  base::merge.data.frame(newlinesDT, newdat, by = NULL)
), use.names = TRUE)[ order(Product,Line),]
#     Product  Line        Name Quantity   Unit  Cost
#      <char> <num>      <char>    <int> <char> <num>
#  1: Antonio 10000      Naiara        4     KG   8.0
#  2: Antonio 20000        Toni        7     KG   3.0
#  3: Antonio 30000        Dany       15      L   2.0
#  4:    Pepe 10000       Lucia        4     UD   8.0
#  5:    Pepe 20000    Santiago        7     UD   5.5
#  6:    Pepe 30000 Mariangeles       10     KG   6.0
#  7:    Pepe 40000        Dany       15      L   2.0
#  8:  Vanesa 10000       Lucia        4     UD   8.0
#  9:  Vanesa 20000    Santiago        7     KG   8.0
# 10:  Vanesa 30000        Toni       10     KG   3.0
# 11:  Vanesa 40000       Gines        4     KG   8.0
# 12:  Vanesa 50000        Dany       15      L   2.0
```

I don't know of a way to get `data.table:::merge.data.table` to allow a cartesian join with no join keys, so I'm forcing the `base`-case here. I *could* add a dummy single-value column to both frames and then join on that column, as another option.